# Strange error for object ID in Samsung SDK

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv

I am having a strange HTML error message for the second line of code below. I am writing an application for the Samsung SMART TV SDK. This uses the Eclipse IDE and uses a Samsung Smart TV Emulator.

```
<object id="pluginPlayer" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER"></object>
<object id="pluginAudio" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-AUDIO"></object>
```

I'm really confused because the error message states "Has same id: clsid". This is coming from the video tutorial. Is there any specific library that I'm not including? These plugins are needed in order to use the low level TV functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be confused. I was too until I realized that this is just an error in Eclipse terms...it actually has no bearing on the app. IGNORE it and continue with your app - it will be just fine. I wasted entire day until I realized that was the case.